# How to fill missing values in a time series on a particular year?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, missing-data, forecasting

I'm like novice in Data Science and I'm trying to solve a Kaggle competition. I have to make an analysis on a time series. In particular there are rainfall values along several years but there aren't any value along a whole year, 2009 in my case.
So my dataset is

[image: Rainfall in 2006]

While the rainfall in 2009 is:

[image: Rainfall in 2009]

To fill the whole missing year, I thought to use the values from previous and next years (2008 an 2010). I know that there are the function `pd.fillna()` and `pd.interpolate(method=time)` from pandas library but they are going to fill missing values with mean and interpolation of the whole year. If I do it, I'll change the whole rainfall distribution since the rainfall measures the amount of rain in a particular date.
My idea was to use a mean on the same day between 2008 and 2010. For example:

`rainfall['2009-01-01'] = (rainfall['2008-01-01'] + rainfall['2010-01-01']) / 2`

It should mean that the rainfall in 2009 looks like at the same day in 2008 and in 2010.
I don't know if my consideration is right since these events are really different every year.
If I use the interpolation method, I get:

`rainfall['2009']= rainfall['2008':'2010'].interpolate(method='time')`

and the result is:

[image: Rainfall in July 2009 after interpolation]

You can see that the rainfall is over 30 along July which means a really weird month since those data are measured in Italy, it's summer and generally the rainfall goes between 0.0 and 1.0 in normal days.
Keep attention that rainfall is amount of raint in a day so generally its behavoiur along year is the following:

[image: Rainfall's behaviour along 2008]

As you can see, there only some peaks in summer days maybe it was a summer downpour.

Therefore, do you suggest how to fill the whole 2009 using the data from previous or next year?

Comment: If I were doing it, I would fill NaN with the mean for each day of  the month, or with the monthly mean, which can be calculated with groupby month and day, or groupby month.

Comment: Clear, I hoped that there was a faster method than computing the mean by hand for each month and day of the year. Maybe the first idea was right